# Main thread not running after goroutine calls exec?

Tags: multithreading, go, exec, goroutine

I was reading about exec in Go https://gobyexample.com/execing-processes, and tried to do the same using goroutines.

In the following code, I'm trying to make Go run `ls`, then print a success message in the main thread. However, it's only printing the ls, but not the success message.

What's going on?

Thanks.

```
package main

import "syscall"
import "os"
import "os/exec"
import "fmt"

func main() {
    p := fmt.Println
    done := make(chan bool)
    binary, lookErr := exec.LookPath("ls")
    if lookErr != nil {
        panic(lookErr)
    }

    args := []string{"ls", "-a", "-l", "-h"}

    env := os.Environ()

    go func() {
        execErr := syscall.Exec(binary, args, env)
        if execErr != nil {
            panic(execErr)
        }
        done <- true
    }()

    <-done

    p("Done with exec")
}
```

Here's the output:

```
Valeriys-MacBook-Pro:test valeriy$ go run test.go 
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  3 valeriy  staff    96B Dec 17 15:46 .
drwxr-xr-x  8 valeriy  staff   256B Dec 17 00:06 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 valeriy  staff   433B Dec 17 15:38 test.go
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`syscall.Exec` replaces the current process with the one invoked.

If you want to run an external command while keeping the original program running, you need to use [exec.Command](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Command)

By the way, the link you included does say:

> Sometimes we just want to completely replace the current Go process
>   with another (perhaps non-Go) one.

If you really want to use the `syscall` package, you can use `syscall.StartProcess` which does a fork/exec as opposed to a plain exec.